# Mobile compatibility CSS

Tags: android, html, css

This is the website I'm working on: 
http://europa333.go.ro/lone/other/

The problem is that everything shows correct on the desktop.

When it comes to tablets and phones , the background messes up + the copyright in the right corner.

It's really bad when you rotate your phone to `landscape`

Anyone has any idea on how could I make this mobile compatible and fix some of those things?

EDIT:

Something I noticed is that the html tag gets height:auto added as style and that is the cause of the white bar at the bottom , how can I fix that?

**EDITx2:** I fixed the height problem using the answer I marked and the text scroll(flexslider issue) I fixed using:

```
    // Listen for orientation changes
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        // Catch the flexslider context
        var slider = $(".flex_text").data("flexslider");

        // Unset the animating flag so we can move back to the first slide quickly
        slider.animating = false;

        // Move to the first slide and restart the slideshow
        slider.flexAnimate(0);
    }, false);
```

Comment: set .flex_text li{min-height:80px} in css and give a try

Comment: @ChandraShekhar That didn't fix anything. I'm not having problems with the scroll text , I'm having problems with the bottom of the page where a white bar gets added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all fixed height (height: 350px;) from landscape media query and use the below style

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) and (min-width: 500px){
   html {
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   .trans-bg{
       overflow-y:scroll;
   }
}
```

you can add the padding to .trans-bg as well. Update the below script on script.js to call flexslider

```
$('.flex_text').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    selector: ".slides li",
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 4000,
    touch: true,
    useCSS: false,
    direction: "vertical",
    smoothHeight:true
});
```

Flexslider already has the option (smoothHeight: true) to set the height of the slide item for vertical scroll, so no need to use the callback function to set the height.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Another problem I'm experiencing is when I rotate from landscape to portrait , the the flex text just messes up (words are on top of other words) . Any idea on how to fix that as well?

Comment: You need to reset the js plugin on window resize or orientationchange

Comment: smoothHeight didn't work. I edited my question on what worked. Thanks a lot for mentioning orientationchange.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from .trans-bg to get rid of the white bar

EDIT:
Also, remove `height: 100%` from .banner

This should remove the white bar completely

Comment: Removing height from banner made the white bar appear again. Its all working except on 'landscape' view on phone. Thats where the white bar gets added.

Comment: Seems like the copyright is what is pushing it down now.
Try chagning from "%" to "px" `bottom: -25px;` on .copyrightt